# How to show result of a query in MessageBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I want to show result of a query  in a MessageBox in C#,  but the code below doesn't work.

```
private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring =
                      @"Data Source=blahblahblah;user id=blah;password=blah;database=blah;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("select blah from blah where blah=@blah");
        check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blah", textBox1.Text);
        con.Open();
        string gholi = check.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(gholi);
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work about what you did there?

Comment: an unhandled exception happen in string gholi = check.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Comment: You need to associate the command with the connection before you can run it. `new SqlCommand("select id from inv where code=@code", con);`

Comment: my mistake... :/, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to see result of code, run application and set breakpoint in first line code.

if you want the next step press F10.

you can see the relevant details with debug code.

Answer (score 0):

You should sql reader to read data from data base or you can use dataset to retrive data from database and then trying display in message box.